# pivot on first field

Tags: sql-server

I have no idea how to do make this work... I have to return my data to look like this

```
 Vendor1, sum(field1), sum(field2), sum(field3), sum(field4)...
 Vendor2, sum(field1), sum(field2), sum(field3), sum(field4)...
 Vendor3, sum(field1), sum(field2), sum(field3), sum(field4)...
 Vendor4, sum(field1), sum(field2), sum(field3), sum(field4)...
```

But, my data keeps returning like so

```
 Vendor1, field1, field2, filed3 field4...
 Vendor1, field1, field2, filed3 field4...
 Vendor1, field1, field2, filed3 field4...
 Vendor1, field1, field2, filed3 field4...
```

Here's a bit of what I have so far

```
select substring(a.warehouse, 2, len(a.warehouse)) as 'Name of Vendor',
 Case 
 when b.status = 3 then
 sum(b.id) over (partition by substring(a.warehouse, 2, len(a.warehouse)))
 else 0
 End as 'Number of Orders',
 Case 
 when b.status = 4 then
 sum(b.P_Name) over (partition by substring(a.warehouse, 2, len(a.warehouse)))
 else 0
 End as 'Number of Items'
 from [Table1]a
 join [Table2]b
 on a.OrderID = b.OrderID
```

I have a number of additional case statements that do similar to the one shown.

What I don't know is **`how to pivot this as a grouping`**.

I hope that I explained things clearly.  Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: Can you post your table structures and some sample data?

Comment: Yeah we need all the relevant data. Table structure, sample rows, everything. That way it's easy to help\

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole select statement in another SELECT and then GROUP BY.
ie:

```
SELECT a.[Name of Vendor], sum(a.[Number of Orders]), sum(a.[Number of Items]), ...
FROM
(
    select substring(a.warehouse, 2, len(a.warehouse)) as 'Name of Vendor',
    Case 
    when b.status = 3 then
    ...
) AS a
GROUP BY a.[Name of Vendor]
```